# Ruby on Rails - Connect to SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I went through some tutorials, but the examples had me create a sqllite3 database, and the solution I want to work on creating is to connect to a SQL server database. I have been searching for how to do this, and following those examples, but it is not coming up properly. I may be missing something. This is what I have:

I ran rails new atdapp at a command line (rails is already installed, and so are gems). I then move into that site directory, and then ran rails server. When I go to
`http://localhost:3000` I get the following error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

This is the info that comes out in the command window that is running the server process:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):

  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve
_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connectio
n'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cac
he_settings'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in
 call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues
/layout (42.0ms)
```

This is in my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: atdapp
  host: xxx-sqlserver
  database: xxxDatabaseName
  port: 1433
  username: xxx
  password: xxx

development:
  <<: *default
adapter: default
```

If anyone has an experience with this, I would love any pointers or ideas.

Thanks!
--Adding Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use sqlserver as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlserver'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: last line in `database.yml` have wrong indentation, it's typo?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  It was not a typo.  I fixed it, but still same issue.